# Dagger 2: Unable to find generated class in Intellij Idea (Kotlin)

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea, kotlin, dagger-2

I was trying to write a application to understand spark and dagger 2. But was unable to use generated dagger files.

There are multiple questions similar to this one, but I am not able to solve the problem using any of those.

My project can be found at github [here](https://github.com/pr-gupta/Pissarra)

The build.gradle file looks like this

```
...
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-kotlin:$spark_kotlin_version"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4j_version"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
....
```

It's the `SparkSetup.kt` Class that I am trying to inject. Module and Component for this are present in `co.pissarra.util.dagger` package

The contents of `SetupModule.kt` looks like this

```
@Module
class SetUpModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSparkSetup() : SparkSetup {
        return SparkSetup()
    }
}
```

And this is `AppComponent.kt` Class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(SetUpModule::class))
interface AppComponent {
    fun sparkSetup() : SparkSetup
}
```

Ideally there should be a class by the name `DaggerAppComponent`, which infact is present in the build directory (both generated and classes). But this only works if I am not using `DaggerAppComponent` anywhere in the project. If I try using this, intellij idea gives the error that `Unresolved reference: DaggerAppComponent` and the project also fails to build.

I would like to change the file `ContainerRunner.kt` and instead of calling `SparkSetup().init()` directly, I would like to have that done through DI.

Comment: I have tried using Dagger with Idea. The generated is probably in the build folder. You have to add that to your source set in your gradle file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like [KT-17923](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17923).
Please update your Kotlin IDE plugin version to 1.1.60 or 1.2-Beta.

Also, as a work-around, you can specify the generated directories manually:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('build/generated/source/kapt/main')
        generatedSourceDirs += file('build/generated/source/kapt/main')
    }
}
```

Note that you need to re-import project after adding this to your `build.gradle`.

The only thing that seems strange for me is that the error also reproduces during the build. Please check if `DaggerAppComponent` lays in the same package with the class that references it (or there is an `import` directive).

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like an IDE (AndroidStudio / IntelliJ) bug.

Facts:

- Generated classes are present in path `build/generated/source/kapt/main`
- Code that uses these generated classes actually works even tough that IDE marks it with red color and `Unresolved reference` error

Fix:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += "$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/main"
}
```

If you use [protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf) there is a similar problem where generated proto classes are not visible (again `Unresolved reference` error)

Fix:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs += file("${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/java")
            srcDirs += file("${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/javalite")
            srcDirs += file("${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/grpc")
        }
    }
}
```